# How to query a geojson point with GraphQl?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, graphql, geojson

I'm working with nodejs, mongoose and graphql and I have geojson 2D coordinates in my db but I'm unable to query them throught graphql it always returns `null`

I've tried with the `PointObject` schema  from https://github.com/ghengeveld/graphql-geojson to replace my `Geometry` schema but same issue

My code :

```
const Geometry = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Geometry',
  fields: () => ({
    type: {
      type: GraphQLString
    },
    coordinates: {
      type: new GraphQLList(GraphQLFloat)
    },
  }),
})

const AntenneType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'AntenneType',
  fields: () => ({
    _id: {
      type: GraphQLID
    },
    type: {
      type: GraphQLString
    },
    geometry: {
      type: Geometry
    },
    properties: {
      type: Properties
    }
  }),
});

const query = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Query',
  fields: {
    antennes: {
      type: new GraphQLList(AntenneType),
      resolve: (obj, args, context, info) => {
        return Antenne.find().limit(2) //Antenne is my mongoose model that return same data as in the data.json file
          .then(antennes => {
            console.log(antennes)
            return antennes
          })
      }
    }
  },
});
```

One set of data :

```
 {
    "properties": {
      ...
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
        2.231666666667,
        49.223611111111
      ]
    },
    "_id": "5cf1901b228293201fe248dc",
    "type": "Feature"
  }
```

My GraphQl query:

```
query{
  antennes{
    _id
    properties{
      generation
      adm_lb_nom
    }
    geometry{
      coordinates 
    }
  }
}
```

And the result :

```
{
  "data": {
    "antennes": [
      {
        "_id": "5cf1901b228293201fe248dc",
        "properties": {
          "generation": "2G",
          "adm_lb_nom": "SFR"
        },
        "geometry": {
          "coordinates": null
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I've also made a gist with my full schemas and data : https://gist.github.com/yadPe/cb397175a8c39021d0dab2208fe22a4d

My mongoose schema (edited according to @DanielRearden answer):

```
const geoSchema = new Schema({
    type: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['Point'],
        required: true
    },
    coordinates: {
        type: [Number],
        required: true
    }
});

const antenneSchema = new Schema({
    type: String,
    properties: {
        sup_id: Number,
        tpo_id: Number,
        sta_nm_dpt: String,
        adr_nm_cp: Number,
        generation: String,
        coordonnees: String,
        sup_nm_haut: Number,
        adm_lb_nom: String,
        emr_lb_systeme: String,
        coord: String,
        emr_dt_service: String,
        date_maj: String,
        code_insee: String,
        nat_id: Number,
        _id: Number,
        com_cd_insee: String,
        id: Number,
        total_de_adm_lb_nom: String,
        sta_nm_anfr: String
    },
    geometry: {
        geoSchema
    }
}, { collection: '2G_France' });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Antenne', antenneSchema);
```

I did some console logging of the data returned by mongoose:

```
Antenne.find().limit(1)
  .then(antennes => {
    //return antennes
    return antennes.map(antenne => {
      console.log(antenne.geometry)
      console.log(typeof antenne.geometry)
      console.log(antenne.geometry.type)
      console.log(antenne.geometry.coordinates)
      const test = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(antenne.geometry)) // idk why I need to do that here
      console.log(test.type)
      console.log(test.coordinates)
      return antenne
    })
  });
```

And got the following result:

```
{ type: 'Point',
  coordinates: [ 2.323333333333, 48.346666666667 ] }
object
undefined
undefined
Point
[ 2.323333333333, 48.346666666667 ]
```

Comment: Hmm. The issue isn't with your schema. Your code [works as expected](https://codesandbox.io/s/howtoqueryageojsonpointwithgraphql-j0efv) when returning just the sample data you provided. I suspect mongoose is not returning the data in the shape we expect, even though it prints correctly to the console. Can you update the question to include your mongoose schema?

Comment: Thank you @DanielRearden for helping me. I've added my mongoose schema to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/geojson.html) show a point schema being defined this way:

```
const geoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  type: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['Point'],
    required: true
  },
  coordinates: {
    type: [Number],
    required: true
  }
});
```

The example in the docs specifically cautions against defining it as `{ type: String }`. I suspect doing so (like in your current code) causes the entire subdocument to be serialized as a String. This would explain what you're seeing because you'd still be able to print the whole subdocument to the console. GraphQL would resolve the `geometry` field to a String, which in JavaScript is technically an Object. However, it wouldn't be able to resolve the `coordinates` or `type` fields because those properties don't exist on a String, causing those fields to resolve to null.

Fix your mongoose schema and that should also fix the field resolution.

EDIT:

Also, you should define `geometry` inside `antenneSchema` like this:

```
geometry: geoSchema
```

or

```
geometry: {
  type: geoSchema
}
```

Comment: I think you pointed out the right issue, but I updated my mongoose schema accordingly to your answer and I still have the same problem. Except that if I do a `JSON.stringify` then a `JSON.parse` to my `antenne.geometry` `object`. I'm able to get a result. I added more information in my question

Comment: Yes it works ! Thank you very much for your help and time. Have a great day